# Valgrind complains data possibly lost

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a callback function in c++ which does this:

```
void MasterInterface::zsock_cb(struct ev_loop *loop, ev_zsock_t *wz, int revents) {

    char iden[MAX_MSG_LEN];
    char msg[MAX_MSG_LEN];
    int numIDBytes = zmq_recv(wz->zsock, iden, sizeof(iden), 0);
    int numBytes = zmq_recv(wz->zsock, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    masterStruct* mStruct = (masterStruct*)wz->data;

    std::string idenData = std::string(static_cast<char*>(iden), numIDBytes);
    std::string msgData = std::string(static_cast<char*>(msg), numBytes);
    cout << "[IN] " << msgData << endl;

    if (!mStruct->synchronized) {
        if (!IDRegistered(mStruct, idenData)) {
            cout << "[IN] " << idenData << endl;
            cout << "[IN] " << msgData << endl;
            mStruct->slaveIDs[mStruct->counter++] = idenData;
            zmq_send (wz->zsock, idenData.c_str(), idenData.size(), ZMQ_SNDMORE);
            zmq_send (wz->zsock, msgData.c_str(), msgData.size(), 0);
        }
            if (mStruct->counter==SLAVES_EXPECTED) {
                sendCommand(wz,"Master connected to slaves.");
                mStruct->synchronized = true;
            }
    }
}

bool MasterInterface::IDRegistered(masterStruct* mStruct, const std::string& id) {

    for (int i=0; i < SLAVES_EXPECTED; i++) {

        if (mStruct->slaveIDs[i]=="") continue;
        if (mStruct->slaveIDs[i].compare(id)==0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I run valgrind on the program, and it reports that 87 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost, indicating that this is the line where the data is "possibly lost".
        std::string idenData = std::string(static_cast(iden), numIDBytes);

I don't think I've done anything wrong here, why does valgrind complain? Is this a false positive?

Thanks.

Here's the mstruct.

```
struct masterStruct {

public:
    int counter;
    bool synchronized;
    std::string slaveIDs[3];
};
```

Compiled with no optimizations. -O0

Here's the valgrind messages:

```
^C[Signal Caught] Closing connections...
Exited Master Process...
==6606== 
==6606== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6606==     in use at exit: 143 bytes in 4 blocks
==6606==   total heap usage: 5,866 allocs, 5,862 frees, 533,480 bytes allocated
==6606== 
==6606== Searching for pointers to 4 not-freed blocks
==6606== Checked 239,000 bytes
==6606== 
==6606== 87 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==6606==    at 0x4A074CC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==6606==    by 0x3A7CC9C3C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6606==    by 0x3A7CC9CDE4: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6606==    by 0x3A7CC9CF6A: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6606==    by 0x402FD5: MasterInterface::zsock_cb(ev_loop*, ev_zsock_t*, int) (MasterInterface.cpp:74)
==6606==    by 0x404C6B: s_check_cb (ev_zsock.c:61)
==6606==    by 0x4E872BC: ev_invoke_pending (ev.c:3155)
==6606==    by 0x4E8BAE1: ev_run (ev.c:3555)
==6606==    by 0x403423: MasterInterface::init() (MasterInterface.cpp:118)
==6606==    by 0x4046DB: main (PXSMaster.cpp:29)
==6606== 
==6606== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6606==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6606==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6606==      possibly lost: 87 bytes in 3 blocks
==6606==    still reachable: 56 bytes in 1 blocks
==6606==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6606== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6606== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==6606== 
==6606== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
--6606-- 
--6606-- used_suppression:      4 U1004-ARM-_dl_relocate_object
==6606== 
==6606== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
bash-4.1$
```

Comment: why do you cast `iden` or `msg` to `char*`? it should be implicit in that situation.

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without seeing `IDRegistered` and `mStruct->slaveIDs`. If I had to guess, I'd bet you never free either `mStruct` or `mStruct->slaveIDs`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode It's just something I tend to do. Does it affect the valgrind situation?

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal, Complet and Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also please provide information on how you compile it (optimizations? compiler?).

Comment: Since you have 3 elements in `slaveIDs` and valgrind is reporting 3 blocks, I can almost guarantee you are not freeing `mStruct`.

Comment: Oh, nah haha I was genuinely curious. Maybe `std::string` had an overload for `char(&)[n]` or something and you were avoiding it.

Comment: @DarkFalcon But, I declare struct like this : struct masterStruct mStruct; It will be deallocated when it goes out of scope, no?

Comment: If it is a global, that depends on how you exit the program. The program must exit normally, which would usually be via a call to `exit` (not `_exit`) or returning from `main`. If it is a local, that depends on whether the stack frame containing it was ever exited. It could not be if you called `exit` within the function containing the local, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dark Falcon is correct.

The MasterInterface class was declared as a global variable. 
In this class, there was

```
struct masterStruct masStruct;
```

In which there is the array of 3 std::string.

This was the issue. When I pressed Ctrl-C, valgrind probably did not take the global variable into account, hence those bytes were possibly lost.

Putting MasterInterface declaration in the main() solved the possibly lost error.